# VBA worksheet function PRODUCT(1+ Range)

Tags: excel, vba, function, product

I'm trying to write a script that utilizes an equation, but in VBA without inserting the equation into a cell; I want to use the function within VBA. In Excel as a formula, I have PRODUCT(1 + Range) where the Range is 11 cells, so it essentially is doing (1 + A1) * (1 + A2) * ... * (1 + A11) along with some other calculations.

`data.Cells(j, cell.Column) = data.Cells(j, cell.Column) + WorksheetFunction.Product(1 + data.Range(Cells(i, cell.Column), Cells(i, cell.Column + 10))) * data.Cells(i, cell2.Column)`

I'm unsure what is going on here, my assumption is that I'm incorrectly using the Product function, is this even possible to do in VBA?

I've tried using the WorksheetFunction Product and it resulted in a Run-Time Error 13.
I'd rather not have to write out (1 + A1) * (1 + A2) * ... * (1 + A11) sort of thing within the code because there is more to the equation that would make the resulting equation impossible to read.

Comment: You cannot add a value to a range of cells like that.  Instead load the range into a variant array and loop that array doing the math.

Comment: What does *"along with some other calculations*" mean? We don't know what `i`, `j`, `cell`, `cell2`, and `data` are, please share the complete relevant code. What does *"there is more to the equation that would make the resulting equation impossible to read"* mean? Please add the additional information to your post.